# python turtle register_shape problem python 3.9

Tags: python

i donno whats wrong with the turtle register shape stuff

i added some images in the same project files and for some reason it doesnt work btw

theres another problem with my code and i dont understand how to solve it

i get this all the time

```
    File "C:\Users\royst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1136, in register_shape
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("Bad arguments for register_shape.\n"
    turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: Bad arguments for register_shape.
    Use  help(register_shape)
```

and i dont understand whats the problem there
plz someone yelp me

```
import turtle
import random

#images
roc= r"C:\Users\royst\PycharmProjects\rps\roc.png"
pap= r"C:\Users\royst\PycharmProjects\rps\pap.png"
sci= r"C:\Users\royst\PycharmProjects\rps\sci.png"


#Creating the screen
win = turtle.Screen()
win.register_shape(roc)
win.register_shape(pap)
win.register_shape(sci)
win.title('Rock Paper Scissors')
win.bgcolor('black')
win.setup(800, 600)
win.tracer(0)



#Shape 1
rock = turtle.Turtle()
rock.shape('roc')
rock.goto(170,100)
rock.speed(0)
rock.color('#AAA49D')
rock.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)
rock.penup()


#Shape 2
paper = turtle.Turtle()
paper.shape('pap')
paper.goto(-170, 100)
paper.speed(0)
paper.color('white')
paper.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)
paper.penup()


#Shape 3
scissors = turtle.Turtle()
scissors.shape('sci')
scissors.goto(0,-170)
scissors.speed(0)
scissors.color('#525252')
scissors.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)
scissors.penup()


#Top text, winner.
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color('white')
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 240)
pen.write("Who wins: ", align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))


#Rock choice.
pen1 = turtle.Turtle()
pen1.speed(0)
pen1.color('white')
pen1.penup()
pen1.hideturtle()
pen1.goto(170, 152)
pen1.write('Rock[R]', align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 16, "normal"))

#Papper choice
pen2 = turtle.Turtle()
pen2.speed(0)
pen2.color('white')
pen2.penup()
pen2.hideturtle()
pen2.goto(-168, 152)
pen2.write('Paper[P]', align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 16, "normal"))

#Scissors choice
pen3 = turtle.Turtle()
pen3.speed(0)
pen3.color('white')
pen3.penup()
pen3.hideturtle()
pen3.goto(0, -118)
pen3.write('Scissors[S]', align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 16, "normal"))


#Player choosing the rock,paper,scissors by pressing specific keys.
def rockfn():
   player_pick = 'rock'
   return player_pick.title()

def paperfn():
   player_pick = 'paper'
   return player_pick.title()

def scissorsfn():
   player_pick = 'scissors'
   return player_pick.title()


#Keys for player choice.
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(rockfn, 'r')
win.onkeypress(paperfn, 'p')
win.onkeypress(scissorsfn, 's')


#Computer random choice
r = 'Rock'
p = 'Paper'
s = 'Scissors'
choice = [r, p, s]
computer_choice = random.choice(choice)



#Main Loop
while True:
   pen.clear()

   if rockfn() or paperfn() or scissorsfn() == computer_choice:
       pen.write("It's a draw", align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))

   elif win.onkeypress(rockfn, 'r'):
       if computer_choice == 'paper'.title():
           pen.write("Computer picked {}, you lost.".format(p.title()), align="center",font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))
       else:
           pen.write('Computer picked {}, you win.'.format(s.title()), align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))

   elif win.onkeypress(paperfn, 'p'):
       if computer_choice == 'scissors'.title():
           pen.write('Computer picked {}, you lost.'.format(s.title()), align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))
       else:
           pen.write('Computer picked {}, you win.'.format(r.title()), align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))

   elif win.onkeypress(scissorsfn, 's'):
       if computer_choice == 'rock'.title():

           pen.write('Computer picked {}, you lost.'.format(r.title()), align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))
       else:

           pen.write('Computer picked {}, you win.'.format(p.title()), align="center", font=("Comic Sans", 24, "normal"))
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape)? `register_shape(name, shape=None)` can be called in three ways: 1. `name` is the name of a gif-file and `shape` is None. 2. `name` is an arbitrary string and `shape` is a tuple of pairs of coordinates. 3. `name` is an arbitrary string and `shape` is a (compound) Shape object. You don't qualify for any of these

Answer (score 0):

I am a 12 years old boy this is my opinion and I think it is true:)

Hi, `win.register()`needs 2 thinks in the parentheses they need name and the shape

When you do `win.register(roc, roc)` and `win.register(pap, pap)` and `win.register(sci, sci)` it works, but there is one more mistake in `rock.shape('rock')` , `paper.shape('pap')` and `scissors.shape('sci')`.
rock, pop and sci are not shapes if you replace them with square, triangle and circle your program works fine